# Default sort by associated field with reverse_relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A miniature may have many contents.

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents, foreign_key: "setmini_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :minisets, :through => :contents, source: :miniset
  has_many :reverse_contents, foreign_key: "miniset_id", class_name: "Content", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :setminis, :through => :reverse_contents, source: :set mini
```

On a miniature's show view I currently list it's contents. What I want to do is add a default sort scope to my Contents model so that it sorts by name.

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { order('name ASC') }
    belongs_to :miniset, class_name: "Miniature"
    belongs_to :setmini, class_name: "Miniature"
```

My attempt here fails and complains "No such column name:".

With a normal has_many_through relationship this would work but I'm guessing because I'm using the join table in two directions and declaring class_name: "Miniature" this doesn't work here.

Is there a way I can get this list to default sort by name?

I've tried "content.name" and "setmini.name" to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some other answers to similar questions I eventually got it working with the following:

default_scope joins(:setmini).order('miniatures.name ASC')

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the name of the database table in your order clause (not the model or association name). If you're following Rails' conventions for naming, this would be:

```
order('contents.name ASC')
```

Comment: It doesn't like that either. "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: contents.name: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contents"  WHERE "contents"."setmini_id" = ?  ORDER BY contents.name ASC LIMIT 1"